# How to make label numbers consistent in lstlisting?

Tags: listings, labels

I have defined two languages using `\lstdefinelanguag` and then setting them using `\lstset`. The point is that later when I write some listing and label them such as.

```
\begin{lstlisting}[language=JavaScript,label={lst:animate}]
\\just some function
\end{lstlisting}
```

The label numbers are not consistent when I reference them with `\ref`. Both the first and the second listing in my document get value `1`. I assume because they are different languages. But then, I have 3 listings from the same language, and again they all have listing value. Any idea how to make listing values increase consistently?

Comment: @clemens It's kind of too long to provide a MWE, but yes, they do coincide. They are in the same section. I though listings work more or less like figures and don't depend on the section. Any idea how to work around this?

Comment: It's never too long for a MWE, look at the example in my answer…

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just a wild guess since you didn't provide a MWE but do the referenced numbers coincide with the section number the listing is in? In order to be able to referende a listing it *needs* to have a caption! The one in your question doesn't have one so the label references whatever counter has been refstepped last.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

\section{bla}
\section{bla}

\begin{lstlisting}[label=lst:foo]
  foo
\end{lstlisting}

First listing without caption: \ref{lst:foo} -- ups! Section number!

Second listing with caption: \ref{lst:bar} -- this looks right!

\begin{lstlisting}[label=lst:bar,caption=bar]
  bar
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A caption and several other numbered document elements do `\refstepcounter{...}` with the corresponding counter and a label *always* refers to the counter for which this has been done the last time before `\label` is used. If the listing has no caption then this can be a `\section` like in my example or something else depending on your actual document. It makes sense: if you refer to **listing 1** then there should be a listing 1 *marked as such* with a caption. Otherwise you will only confuse your readers.